# pandas skip stop in timetable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timetable

I am trying to skip some stops in a pandas timetable which looks like this:

```
    departure   arrival     in  out
0   a           b           1   0
1   b           '#delete'   2   0
2   '#delete'   d           0   3
3   d           e           1   1
```

I try to skip the #delete values in the timetable and join the in and out values:

```
    departure   arrival     in  out
0   a           b           1   0
1   b           d           2   3
2   d           e           1   1
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

EDIT:
A little modification of Wen's solution worked for me:

```
df = df.mask(df=="#delete")
df.arrival = df.arrival.fillna(method='ffill')
df.departure = df.departure.fillna(method='bfill')
df = df.groupby(['arrival', 'departure']).sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More like a customize `fillna` problem

```
df=df.mask(df=="'#delete'")
df.departure=df.departure.ffill()

df.arrival=df.arrival.bfill()

df.groupby(['departure','arrival'],as_index=False).sum()
Out[761]: 
  departure arrival  in  out
0         a       b   1    0
1         b       d   2    3
2         d       e   1    1
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified your solution a little and it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested):

```
skipfrom = np.where(df.arrival == '#delete')[0]
skipto = skipfrom + 1
df.arrival[skipfrom] = df.arrival[skipto].values
df.out[skipfrom] = df.out[skipto].values
df = df[df.departure != '#delete']
```